# Maven: Compiling package-info.java to package-info.class?

Tags: java, maven-2, compilation, package

I have package-info.java in my package, Hibernate wants it for some features (programatic entity scanning).

However, `mvn package` does not result in `package-info.class` being in `classes/` thus not in the artifact.

How can I force that happening?

```
mvn -v
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 21:16:01+0200)
Java version: 1.6.0_26
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.35-30-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Comment: Which version of maven compiler plugin?  Could you be hitting http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-71?  You could post the relevant pom snippet as well

Comment: Raghuram, good catch, but ironically, when I added annotation, it started working :)Compiler plugin 2.3.2, source & target = 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was that the `package-info.java` must have any annotation with `Retention=RUNTIME` to compile into a class. Otherwise, JDK 6 omits it.
I used `@Deprecated` which is the only one in Java SE (and I  didn't want to introduce an annotation just because of that).

```
@Deprecated
package cz.zizka.ondra.packageinfo.test
```

Comment: You should have introduce the extra annotation for this purpose.

Answer (score 12):

Give `-Xpkginfo:always` option to javac.

See the

- [`javac` 1.8 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)
- [`javac` 17 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html)

Comment: Thanks for adding. It wasn't available at the time - added in JDK 7.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution (inspired by zbyszek's answer) is to add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Xpkginfo:always</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

Works correctly in Maven 3; don't know about 2.  Is it possible that the package declaration in package-info.java is missing or wrong?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by "works correctly" because I tried and maven 3.6.0 does not generate `package-info.class` files where I stand :/